# Custom CSS is messing with Kendo UI Grid

Tags: css, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI (jQuery) Grid with pager. The designer has added a very heavy `common.css` to the project and it has affected the pager portion of the grid (and nothing else):

[image: Custom CSS file messes with Kendo Grid]

As you can see the highlighted `ul` is getting some style from `common.css` (`margin-bottom: 15px;`). Here is the CSS element:

```
#mainContent > .container .sfContentBlock ul {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

I need to exempt kendo from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have overwrite it.

Below line 2765 in common.css
Or in a css file loaded afterwards.

```
#mainContent > .container .sfContentBlock ul {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Or target these uls specifically.

```
#mainContent ul.k-pager-numbers {
    margin-bottom: 0 ! important;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `!important` unless an in-line style has been applied (mostly by some Javascript  library/plugin).
Use a more specific selector instead